# TypeError: _parse_args() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'

Tags: numpy, scipy

I got an error, though I found that similar error has been posted there, but it does not lead to me a conclusion, here is the code and error is related to size. Well my friend used the same code and it worked for him but I got above mentioned error.

```
enter code here
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  n=100
  alpha=5
  alpha1=2
  np.random.seed(1)
  x=10*ss.uniform.rvs(size=n) 
  y=alpha+alpha1*x+ss.norm(loc=0, scale=1, size=n) 
  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(x,y,"o", ms=10)
  xx=np.array([0,10])
  plt.plot(xx, alpha+alpha1*x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ss.norm` does not accept argument `size` you passed to it.

Did you mean:

```
 y=alpha+alpha1*x+ss.norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=n)
```

output of first plot:

[image]

I am guessing there is a typo in your last line too, did you mean:

```
 plt.plot(xx, alpha+alpha1*xx)
```

output of this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, but as told you that my friend used the same code and it worked for him but why it is not working for me? do you know the reason

Comment: it is either a typo or your friend might be using an older version of the package that might have different arguments for the function `norm`. I cannot think of other reasons.